# Sums and more on Hilbert spaces

Tags: operator-theory

We know that the sum of two bounded Operators is bounded and therefore also closed. But there is a fact which is more deep but i don't see the proof. Th result js the following: The sum of a closed (possible unbounded) Operator T on $D(T)$  and a bounded operator S is a closed one.

Can someone help me? I think that i have to look to the graph of T+S. Some hints or solutions to this Problem?

Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let $V=T+S$. To show that $V$ is closed, we must verify that 
$$x_n\to x \ \text{ and } \ Vx_n \to y \implies y=Vx \tag{1}$$
Since $S$ is bounded, $Sx_n\to Sx$. Therefore, $Tx_n = Vx_n-Sx_n\to y-Sx$. Since $T$ is closed, $y-Sx = Tx$. Thus $y=Vx$ as required.